# "Производить" и "вырабатывать"

Tags: разница

what it the difference between the two verbs, examples very welcome

Comment: What does the dictionary say?

Comment: @Pandora "prior research effort is indicated"  is an important part ;)

Answer (score 3):

These verbs are synonyms in common meanning,but there are nuances.Производить ~it means to produce eg.goods,etc.
Eg.-завод производит автомобили.
Вырабатывать~this word in its meaning also can be  closer to the development of a certain quantity of goods or something else (output).Especially the derivative noun "выработка"(after б alternating vowels а and о)
Eg.зарплата зависит от выработки (salary depends on output).
Also thre are many homonyms of these verbs.Eg.производить впечатление(Make an impression)
вырабатывать(добывать) ископаемые(руду,уголь)-ore, coal mining.